# Using React to render D3 BarChart ( Cannot read properties of undefined)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, d3.js, tsx

I'm learning React.js. I want to print a simple barChart with D3. So have two .tsx files. The first is app.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import BarChart from './BarChart';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { useRef } from 'react';
declare var require: any

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70];

    console.log(data)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>D3 and React Bar Chart</h1>
            <BarChart data={data} width={700} height={400} />
        </div>
    );
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The second is BarChart.tsx:

```
import { select, scaleBand, scaleLinear, axisBottom, axisLeft, max } from 'd3';

interface BarChartProps {
    data: number[];
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

const BarChart: React.FC<BarChartProps> = ({ data, width, height }) => {
    const svgRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement | null>(null);
    const xAxisGroupRef = useRef<SVGGElement | null>(null);
    const yAxisGroupRef = useRef<SVGGElement | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!svgRef.current || !xAxisGroupRef.current || !yAxisGroupRef.current) return;

        const svg = select(svgRef.current);

        const xScale = scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map((_, index) => index.toString()))
            .range([0, width])
            .padding(0.5);

        const yScale = scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, max(data) as number])
            .range([height, 0]);

        const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale);
        const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale);

        select(xAxisGroupRef.current).call(xAxis);
        select(yAxisGroupRef.current).call(yAxis);

        svg
            .selectAll('.bar')
            .data(data)
            .join('rect')
            .attr('class', 'bar')
            .attr('x', (d, index) => xScale(index.toString()) as number)
            .attr('y', d => yScale(d))
            .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr('height', d => height - yScale(d))
            .attr('fill', 'steelblue');
    }, [data, width, height]);

    return (
        <svg ref={svgRef} width={width} height={height}>
            <g>
                <g ref={xAxisGroupRef} transform={`translate(0, ${height})`}></g>
                <g ref={yAxisGroupRef}></g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    );
};

export default BarChart;
```

Here is the error on the debug console:

> BarChart.tsx:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')
> at BarChart (BarChart.tsx:48:9)
> at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
> at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26560:1)
> at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)

I'm not sure why the svgRef is not getting created or what I need to do to have it be created. I'd appreciate any insight anyone has here.

I was expecting a simple bar chart to render.

Here is my index.html file:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/app-bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```